# completed task not showing in api call

Tags: activecollab

I am using API for this, but only showing active task completed task not showing in the result.

Sample Call
=> projects/1/tasks

Does somebody have an idea about this? why it is not showing?

Comment: Can you please provide some context, such as what you trying to accomplish, what language/framework, code you wrote and what result you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to hit a different endpoint of the project task archive: `/projects/1/tasks/archive`

Per [the documented example](https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/projects/elements/tasks/archive.html), this endpoint appears **only** show completed tasks. If you were looking to get all tasks for a project, you may need to use one of the reporting endpoints or merge the results of `projects/1/tasks` and `projects/1/tasks/archive`.